# Controllers in my code base in swift is defined as struct not classes

Tags: swift3, static, static-methods, swift-class

I am from Objc background & new to swift.

What does this comment means "/// Used in a static manner"

```
/// Used in a static manner
struct RecentItemsController {
    fileprivate init() { }
}
```

DO I really need this init()?

In the whole code base I have not written RecentItemsController(), then why need this constructor definition?

Answer (score 0):

The fileprivate guarantees that you *can't* instantiate new objects from this class. So this is not possible:

```
let recentItemsController = RecentItemsController()
```

**Note**: the '()'.

I *assume* it was intended to be used as a singleton.

That's what's makes it static, and that's why you have never have written or find a new instantiation of this class.

You should have a shared instance of this static class along the lines of this in your `RecentItemsController` class:

```
static let sharedRecentItemsController = RecentItemsController()
```

and use that instance everywhere it's needed like so:

```
let recentItemsController = RecentItemsController.sharedRecentItemsController
```

which guarantees that you use the same object everywhere in your code (hence, static).

*extra info:*

`fileprivate` is almost the same as just a regular `private` attribute, which contains it in that class, but makes it useable in extensions.

Also read more on static and singleton classes in this nice blogpost [here](https://krakendev.io/blog/the-right-way-to-write-a-singleton)

**Edit**

I thought i'd add this: It could also be that the init is set to private to absolutely guarantee that no new instance can be made of the struct because structs provide a memberwise initializer:

> Structure types automatically receive a memberwise initializer if they do not define any of their own custom initializers. Unlike a default initializer, the structure receives a memberwise initializer even if it has stored properties that do not have default values. - [Apple Developer, section: Memberwise Initializers for Structure Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html)

So if you were actually using it as a Singleton it would be better to use a class than a struct.